# Как объединить две формулы в google sheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

При запросе  url адрес отдаёт массив вида:

```
[51,13,79,10]
```

Я научился получать данные в стоблец формулой:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("url" ,","))
```

результат:

```
[51
13
79
10]
```

Второй формулой я оставляю только цифры:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A3),A3,REGEXEXTRACT(T(A3),"\d+"))
```

и получается нужный мне результат:

```
51
13
79
10
```

Вопрос: как объединить эти две формулы в одну?
Все попытки не увенчались успехом(

Заранее благодарен за любую подсказку.

Comment: Так не сработает? `=REGEXEXTRACT(T(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("url" ,","))),"\d+")` А вообще - показать на листе пример

Comment: так работает но публикует одну строку

Comment: Читайте и то, что в комментарии после формулы написано...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=arrayformula(ЕСЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(
TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("url" ,","))
),
TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("url" ,","))
,REGEXEXTRACT(T(
TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("url" ,","))
),"\d+")))

Попробуй этот вариант.
Читается как: К массиву(arrayformula), в котором(Если) числовые значения(ечисло) оставить как есть(изначальный массив), а из не числовых(false), вычленить числа(REGEXEXTRACT).

Comment: Да, так работает. Но если я правильно понимаю, то в процессе вычисления идёт как минимум три запроса на сервер. А можно сократить до одного?

Comment: Ну, тогда будут две отдельные формулы. положи transpose в, скажем А2, а вместо transpose в формуле пропиши a2:a. Так тоже будет работать